# Xen DomUs with private IPs

Tags: linux, networking, xen

I have a server with a public IP in eth0 and routed network config.

I have created DomUs with private IPs (10.0.1.x) and they can ping Dom0 and other private IPs, however I want them to ping the outer world.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research, here are the commands to be executed on the Dom0. Replace `$VIF_NAME` with the virtual interface name of your Xen VM.

**Add forwarding**

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
iptables -A FORWARD -o eth0 -i $VIF_NAME -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -o $VIF_NAME -i eth0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

**Remove forwarding**

```
VIF_NAME="vif${VM}"
IDS=$(iptables -L FORWARD -nv --line-numbers | grep "$VIF_NAME" | cut -d' ' -f1 | sort -r)
for id in $IDS; do
  iptables -D FORWARD $id
done
```